# TYPO3 EXT:cart_product: extend backend with one selection to do conditional theming in template

Tags: typo3, cart, fluid

I'm looking for a way to extend the backend of the TYPO3 extension cart_products with one additional select field. I have already created some different ViewHelpers for the ProductBackendVariants and now need a way to choose the corresponding Viewhelper.

Best would be if there is a selection direct after the type select in the general product type. But I am not able to add some additional configuration fields to this tab.

Already added

```
'formtemplate' => [   
    'label' => 'ProductDetail Variant Form',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => [
            ['Standard', 1],
            ['Matten', 2],
            ['Zaunpaket', 3],
        ],
        'size' => 1,
        'minitems' => 1,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ],
],
```

to the `tx_cartproducts_domain_model_product_product.php` but nothing appears in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that specific extension but some hints in general:

- it seems that you have tried to modified the TCA directly in the extension (`cart_products/Configuration/TCA/tx_cartproducts_domain_model_product_product.php`). You should never change anything in a 3rd party extension (neither the TYPO3 core) because you loose the ability to update.
- You need to create your own extension and add a file to `Configuration/TCA/Overrides`. Ideally you name the file exactly like the file you like to extend for easier understanding. See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html) for details.
- To add a new field to the TCA you not only need to define the name and type but you also need to create the database field. That's done in `ext_tables.sql` of your custom extension.
- It's not sufficent to create the TCA config and SQL mentioned above you also need to tell, where the new field should be visible in the backend. That's done with the `showitem` setting. See [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Types/Properties/Showitem.html#types-properties-showitem) for details.
- To ease the process of extending an existing TCA I can recommend the extension [TCA Builder](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/tcabuilder/) which makes it in many cases much easier to create the TCA code. See these [examples](https://git.spooner.io/spooner-web/tcabuilder/-/blob/main/README.md#examples-tca-builder) how that's done. Nevertheless you need to create `ext_tables.sql`.
- Last but not least: when you made changes to `ext_tables.sql` you need to run the database compare in the TYPO3 install tool.